# Saving list content and restoring it on orientation change is very slow in android

Tags: android, listview, adapter, screen-orientation

I am saving my array list and restoring it from saveinstancestate on orientation changes but restoring mechanism is very very slow. 
I have checked by commenting restoring code in on create view - in this case it works fast but if i try with restoring its hang up my screen. 
Below is what i am doing:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    videoEntityList = (ArrayList<VideoListEntity>) savedInstanceState
                            .getSerializable("someExpensiveObject");

    VideoListAdapter adapter = new VideoListAdapter( DashboardActivity.this, R.layout.dashboard_list_row,
                        videoEntityList , videoList, travelReady, s3, activity, width, height);
    videoList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and for saving:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("someExpensiveObject", videoEntityList);
}
```

Please help what are alternate ways to make it work fast

Comment: Don't use Serializable, use Parcelable, it's much faster http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Comment: have tried this. Can see only small time difference

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's the `getSerializable` call that's causing the delay, not the `setAdapter` call for example?

Comment: Yes, you are right its setAdapter that is taking time

Comment: Then it's nothing to do with your serialisation or unserialisation but about how your adapter draws views....

Comment: In your adapter make sure you are using the ViewHolder pattern and following various performance tweaks described here and elsewhere http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html